# Analyzing AngularJS code with SonarQube but output is not satisfactory

Tags: angularjs, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am using sonarcube for analyzing my angularjs code everything runs fine but no errors are populated. Analyzing is success.

Comment: This is my sonar properties configuration:sonar.projectKey=my:project
sonar.projectName=scp_code_11042017
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.language=js
sonar.profile=eslint-angular
sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml
sonar.sii.quality.html.file.metrics.skip=true
sonar.sii.quality.css.file.metrics.skip=true
sonar.sii.js.suffixes=.js
sonar.sii.duplication.html.skip=true
sonar.sii.duplication.css.skip=true
sonar.sii.quality.angular.eslint.report.path=/reports/sonar/eslint-angular.json
sonar.sources=E:/scp_code_11042017/main/app/src/main/content/jcr_root/apps/nedbank-scp-core

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
sonar.inclusions=**/web/**/*
```

adapt with your directory

Comment: there is no web in my project. It contains only js files. It's analyzing js files but not getting any errors right now. I have added the rules as well.

Comment: are you sure .js files are scanned ? did you see theses files in 'code' menu ?